# Define dataframe based on selected ActionButton in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have 3 action buttons (base,best,worst) and 3 dataframes (also called base,best,worst).

I want that the new data frame I am trying to create, forecast, is populated (or generated?), according to the button the user clicks.Ive tried something like below but i am getting an "object not found, error".Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
forecast <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame())
      
      observeEvent(input$base, {
        data<-base
          })
      
      observeEvent(input$best, {
        data<-best
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$worst, {
        data<-worst
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the name `forecast` of the `reactiveValues`:

```
forecast <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame())
      
      observeEvent(input$base, {
        forecast$data<-base
          })
      
      observeEvent(input$best, {
        forecast$data<-best
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$worst, {
        forecast$data<-worst
      })
```

Comment: Still getting the same error! Wouldnt that be like adding a new column in an empty data frame instead of creating a new dataframe like im trying to do ?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a minimal reproducible example of your shiny app with the problem for further analysis?